# InvalidOperationException in CommonSaveFileDialog of WindowsAPICodePack

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-api-code-pack

I'm using CommonSaveFileDialog of WindowsAPICodePack in WPF to ask the user for a filename. In order to check the filename before the dialog is closed, I have a handler for FileOk. But if I try to get the FileName property, there is an InvalidOperationException thrown saying that this property is not available before the dialog is closed.

So how can I retrieve the full file name that the user selected or entered, when in FileOk handler?

Comment: Yes, that's a flaw in the code.  It is technically fixable by calling PopulateFileNames in OnFileOk and changing CheckFileNamesAvailable.

Comment: Ok, so if there is no other possibility to get the file name, I will workaround this problem by checking after the dialog is closed.

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround as suggested by Hans Passant without modifying source code :

```
dialog.FileOk += (sender, e) =>
{
    var filenames = new Collection<string>();
    typeof(CommonFileDialog)
        .GetMethod("PopulateWithFileNames", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        .Invoke(dialog, new[] { filenames });

    // use filenames
}
```